# How to select a post with no comments?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

How to create the such query by a standart way (not using raw SQL)?

Then I need to add more conditions.

E.g.

```
class Post( models.Model ):
    title = models.CharField( max_length = 128 )
    text = models.TextField()

class Comment( models.Model ):
    post = models.ForeignKey( Post )
    text = models.TextField()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify `comment` with `None`:

```
Post.objects.filter(comment=None)
```

You can add more conditions using addtional `filter` or `exclude`.